# No line found error when using Scanner class

Tags: java, android-studio

This is a very simple script but it keeps throwing no line found error. I don't know what am I doing wrong. The error is this

> I/System.out: Enter username
>   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>    Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Since this is a code in Android Studio, I don't know if I need to make any changes in the XML for this. Here is the XML for this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Input">


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Java code

```
public class Input extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_input);
            Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter username");


            // Enter username and press Enter

            String userName = myObj.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Username is: " + userName );

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use edittext for taking inputs. Scanner may not be good approach

Comment: Hi, this should rather be a comment than an answer as It does not provide a solution to he question without further explanations...